# How to programmatically enable "show touches" option in Android?

Tags: android, touch, settings

I want to enable "show touches" in Settings of Android device. Here is the link, which show us the way to access "touch settings", but I didn't find there the way to access "show touches".
[How to programmatically check, get and set touch settings in android phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557816/how-to-programmatically-check-get-and-set-touch-settings-in-android-phones/26402518#26402518)

Help me, please!

Comment: There shouldn't be a way to do this, except perhaps on rooted devices. None of the developer options should be programmatically controllable.

Comment: I mean how to do it on rooted devices. I use some apps (for Root only) and they could enable/disable "show touches"

Comment: I found what I wanted

Comment: Sunshinetpu please share that...

Comment: @BrunodeLima Please see my new answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I found:

To enable **show touches**:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                "show_touches", 1);
```

To disable **show touches**:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                "show_touches", 0);
```

Remember to add `android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS`to your `Manifest`.

Comment: Just so people are aware, this no longer works on Marshmallow, but is the correct way to do it on previous versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

if  still not works Use solution Given By Top And Change Target Version to 22 in Manifest File. it will work fine
Thanks for Answer TOP.