# Draw all the touching points on full devices (android 6.0+)

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I tried to make an app can draw all the touching points when users touching their own device. (it's mean that even outside the app.)

At first, I add a view overlay on the device. But if I fetch the touch points on the top of screen, it seems to block the entire screen and I can't let the touch get through the view to touch other unit under the view.

At second, I write "show_touches" settings of system, then I can see all the touch points.

The second way worked fine until android 6.0 release. Above 6.0, I need to request permission again in the app. But when the permission granted, I still get a crash "You cannot change private secure settings".

Is there any way to get secure settings permission? Or another way to draw touch points on the top of screen?

I need an answer without rooted, can anyone help me figure it out?

this is my stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.morshues.mytestapp, PID: 31194
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=45487, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.morshues.mytestapp/com.morshues.mytestapp.SecondActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3988)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4038)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:150)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1443)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot change private secure settings.
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
   at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
   at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
   at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1400)
   at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1769)
   at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:1874)
   at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:1868)
   at com.morshues.FullRecorder.start(FullRecorder.java:238)
   at com.morshues.FullRecorder.onActivityResult(FullRecorder.java:132)
   at com.morshues.mytestapp.onActivityResult(MainCenter.java:130)
   at com.morshues.mytestapp.SecondActivity.onActivityResult(SecondActivity.java:91)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6439)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3984)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4038) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:150) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1443) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: I requested PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS, but I still get crash even "System.canWrite(activity)" is true

Comment: can you post the stacktrace

Comment: This is not directly helpful to solving your problem (and you may be aware of this already), but I know my Android's `Settings -> Developer options -> Input -> Show touches` and `Show pointer location` do what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: sure! I edited my post.

Comment: @AaronCarson I know this way but my customer said that is too cumbersome.

Comment: This is interesting, although it may require developer options to be enabled: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402813/how-to-programmatically-enable-show-touches-option-in-android

Comment: @AaronCarson this is my current way, and this method will be crash above android 6.0+

Comment: Ah, my apologies :-)

Comment: @AaronCarson That's fine, thanks for your suggestions.