# how to enable Show Touch pointer in android screen?

Tags: android

I want to enable or disable like show below image

[image]

I am using android studio and Maximum API level 23 and i want to enable or disable programmatically. i am use this

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),"Show Touch",1); 

code but not working but it will send a error that 
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: com.zennaxx.touchingeffect was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:646)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$NameValueCache.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1322)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$System.putStringForUser(Settings.java:1671)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$System.putIntForUser(Settings.java:1776)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.provider.Settings$System.putInt(Settings.java:1770)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.zennaxx.touchingeffect.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:26)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-25 12:13:36.059 23858-23858/com.zennaxx.touchingeffect E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-25 12:16:14.349 23858-23858/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23858 SIG: 9
```

please any one can help me.

Comment: Did you try adding android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS to your manifest?

Comment: i add this permission but it worked in API level <=23 but not working in API level >=23

Comment: I believe this question has been answered earlier:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402813/how-to-programmatically-enable-show-touches-option-in-android

Comment: i follow that but it was send an error as i posted above

Answer (score -1):

from API level 23 you have to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: have you request permission for WRITE_SETTINGS . I am not talking about manifest permission but getting permission from user that you have to do from marshmallow.

Comment: i think that you talking about dynamically get the permission in java file that i also do but not working  i do like this                                              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS},1);
        }

Comment: have you calling onRequestPermissionsResult?

Comment: no, because in other app i am not calling than also work that's why i am not calling that method

Comment: in that case please go through a link I provided.

Comment: This is not a permission that you can request permission for. Runtime permissions are irrelevant for this.