# how to add touch pointer to aplication?

Tags: java, android, pointers, touch

I'm developing simple drawing application and I was wondering if it is possible to add visible pointer when touching canvas? What I mean is something similar to mouse indicator on PC. The reason for that is - when using eraser it is not visible where exactly your touch is registered and with the pointer, it would help (especially when using finger touch, because the pen is quite precise). I've tried with other similar topics but none of them answered the question.

Comment: The answer is yes.

Comment: What about the answer for the title question?

Comment: You said "I've tried". Show us that.

Comment: I've tried searching... I didn't code anything because none of the similar questions had the answer. I thought this was obvious from the following part of the sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

taken from this pos : 
 [How to programmatically enable "show touches" option in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402813/how-to-programmatically-enable-show-touches-option-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

• enable show touches:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
            "show_touches", 1);
```

• To disable show touches:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
            "show_touches", 0);
```

Remember to add android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS to your Manifest.

EDIT:

here is a [DrawView.java](https://github.com/ByoxCode/DrawView/blob/master/drawview/src/main/java/com/byox/drawview/views/DrawView.java) that implements View.OnTouchListener and defines multiple draw modes. however it lacks the indicators.

in main activity inside setListener for the DrawView you override onStartDrawing method: here you can decide whether or not to show an indicator and how to style it depending on DrawView's current mode ( pen ,eraser etc ) and on the other interface methodes move the indicator if its visible and hide it when drawing ends. check the code:

```
            mDrawView.setOnDrawViewListener(new DrawView.OnDrawViewListener() {
                @Override public void onStartDrawing() {
                    canUndoRedo();
                    // decide whether or not to show an
                    // indicator and style it depending on
                    // mDrawView's attributes and current drawing mode

                    setIndicator(mDrawView.getDrawingMode(),mDrawView.getDrawWidth());
                }

                @Override
                public void onMove(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    if(isIndicatorVisible){
                        indicatorView.animate()
                                .x(motionEvent.getX())
                                .y(motionEvent.getY())
                                .setDuration(0)
                                .start();
                    }

                }

                @Override public void onEndDrawing() {
                    canUndoRedo();
                    //hide indicator here
                    if (isIndicatorVisible){
                        indicatorView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isIndicatorVisible = false;

                    }

                }
```

here is the edits that i add to DrawView.java :

defined new interface method  void onMove(MotionEvent motionEvent)

```
  public interface OnDrawViewListener {
        void onStartDrawing();

        void onEndDrawing();

        void onClearDrawing();

        void onRequestText();

        void onMove(MotionEvent motionEvent); // added this method
    }
```

called the new method inside onToch:

```
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                onDrawViewListener.onMove(motionEvent); // added this line
                mDrawMoveHistory.get(mDrawMoveHistory.size() - 1).setEndX(motionEvent.getX()).setEndY(motionEvent.getY());

                if (mDrawingTool == DrawingTool.PEN || mDrawingMode == DrawingMode.ERASER) {
                    mDrawMoveHistory.get(mDrawMoveHistory.size() - 1).getDrawingPathList()
                            .get(mDrawMoveHistory.get(mDrawMoveHistory.size() - 1).getDrawingPathList().size() - 1)
                            .lineTo(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());
                }
                invalidate();
                break;
```

here's setIndicator method :

```
    private void setIndicator(DrawingMode drawingMode, int drawWidth) {
        if (drawingMode == DrawingMode.ERASER){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(drawWidth, drawWidth);
            indicatorView.setLayoutParams(params);
            GradientDrawable border = new GradientDrawable();
            border.setStroke(1, 0xFF000000); //black border with full opacity
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                indicatorView.setBackgroundDrawable(border);
            } else {
                indicatorView.setBackground(border);
            }
            indicatorView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            isIndicatorVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've seen this post earlier and this's not entirely what I need, but to be perfectly sure I've tried it with my code. It works as a workaround only, because I get an outline of the spot I touch. What I asked for is a pointer which would draw/erase exactly as much as it's size (drawing/erasing is already covered). And I want it only on the canvas, because on the toolbox or anywhere else it is useless.

Comment: Another problem is that this seems to work only for API <23. Later versions won't allow changing private settings so question stays open.

Comment: i edited the answer .. the code is based on this github project : https://github.com/ByoxCode/DrawView.. i tried the changes i made and it's working fine .. good luck

Comment: Thanks, that looks great and seems useful, but it seems I may need more of your help. I've tried to make it as simple as possible just to see if it works. I have made simple view (stored in the same layout where drawingView is). I called it from drawingView inside onTouchEvent (tell me if there is a better way):
if (pointer == null) {
            pointer = ((MainActivity) context).getPointer();
        }
Next I have used the same what you have in onMove and put it in case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
No errors or exceptions, app works fine, just there is no indicator. Any help with that?

Comment: Kill me! I was doing so many changes for testing purpose and I forgot that I have deleted android:src from my view. So basically I was animating a ghost :D Successfully, but still a ghost. Thanks!